# Unable to see secrets -even with new access policy- in key vault automatically created with my bot resource

Tags: azure, bots, azure-keyvault

I created my first Azure bot resource and I'm trying to retrieve the app's password. However, when I access the key vault created in the resource group, I see no secrets whatsoever. This is *after* I assigned myself enough permissions to be able to 'list' secrets (actually, I assigned myself permissions to not only list, but to do every possible action on secrets). The permissions model used in this key vault is the original 'vault access policy'. Any suggestions on why I am not seeing any secret in this key vault and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the creation of Azure Bot, if you use **user-assigned managed identity** as type of your app, you do not need to manage the bot's credentials yourself. Azure will manage it for you

**So, you would not be able to see the app password as secret in the Azure Key Vault**

When the type of App is **single-tenant** or **multi-tenant** with new app ID, the app password generated will be stored in the Azure Key Vault

**Now, with proper access policy, you would be able to access the app password from the Azure Key Vault secrets**

Comment: Thanks @RamaraoAdapa-MT, making my bot resource a Single Tenant app has apparently given me access to the app's password. I'm surprised that Microsoft's documentation does not clearly warn users about avoiding the use of 'User assigned Managed identity', especially when users plan to build and host their bots *outside* of the Microsoft cloud, although integrate with the Bot Framework via channels.